Help ID a film about an African American scientist recounting her time in a secret research facility while wearing a white mask
I was a kid when I watched this but I never got to finish it and it has been bugging me.  It's been over nine years.
It was a movie about scientists carrying out research in a secret research facility with aborted fetuses in order to find a serum that can make a dead heart beat on its own. No one can leave this facility.
One of the scientists is an African American female scientist who recounts the story of her time in the facility to interviewers while wearing a white mask that covered her entire face covered.
Another thing that I need to add was that in the facility, they kept women who would be pregnant by men in there and abortions would be carried out by who I think is the lead scientist who was a white woman who wore glasses.
One of the women kept for the abortion tried to leave the lab and was killed, so they tested the self heart beating serum on her, she was reanimated but her reanimated body went on a rampage until she was killed for the second time.
The scientist who was an African American female scientist would jog everyday through the corridors of the secret lab which were pure white. No one was allowed to lead the lab.

It isn't The Lazarus Effect, Splice, or The Facility.

I think you are describing the plot of The Prometheus Project (2010), also known as The Frankenstein Syndrome.

A group of researchers conducting illegal stem cell research discover a cell anomaly that has the potential to regenerate dead tissue. Unable to conduct legal human trials, the researchers turn to corpses to test their serum.


There’s a review that recaps a lot of the elements you recall, including the very memorable narrator who wears a white mask  and is confined to a wheelchair.
